# Error in Azure Application Initialisation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure webapplication and when it goes through the application-initialization scripts I keep getting these

```
Error message
System.Web.HttpException: The request is not supported. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x80070032)

Sample stack trace
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070032. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070032): The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginWriteInternal>b__46_0(Object )
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.IO.Stream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteStreamedResponseContentAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

Its driving us mad as if we hit the same addresses after initialisation they work fine. This only happens on Azure it never happens when we run the application locally where they work fine.

Any thoughts... the inner code indicates that its unable to attach to a 64bit process but we are running in 32bit.

Cheers

Comment: Could you please share which application-initialization scripts  you have set in your web config?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I have exactly the same issue and found this while trying to investigate :)

Comment: @user1259167 no sadly not but if you find out let me know I’m desperate

Comment: FYI this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571247/azure-iis-application-initialization-preload-logs-a-the-request-is-not-suppor - no luck finding a solution yet...